# control page to move to top in case of confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

The following is my code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table#example td a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            alert("You Press OK");
        }

    });
});
```

My grid-view is on the bottom of the page. Either I press Ok or Cancel Button, page moves to TOP.

I want to remain the same position. How to control this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually doesn't have anything to do with the `confirm`; it's the fact you're clicking a link (I'm guessing the link has either `href=""` or `href="#"` in it). The browser is following the link, which is the default action for the `click` event of links.

You need to prevent the default action, which you can do by returning `false` from your function, or by accepting the `event` argument to your `click` function and calling [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Returning `false` (which both prevents the default action and stops the click bubbling to ancestor elements):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table#example td a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            alert("You Press OK");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Using `preventDefault` (which only prevents the default, and doesn't stop bubbling; ancestor elements will also see the click):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Note argument -----------------------------v
    $('table#example td a.delete').click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            alert("You Press OK");
        }
    });
});
```